# Sitecore - is it possible to configure multiple URLs for a single node?

Tags: sitecore

I have dozens of local, child websites under my national website. Some of these child nodes need to be able to support multiple URL requests, for example:

www.NationalSite.com/local/region1/east-side.aspx

and

www.NationalSite.com/local/region1/west-side.aspx

Is it possible to have both of these URLS point to the same node in Sitecore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your version of Sitecore, you could use clones or proxies.

On the SDN, there's a document called [Reusing and Sharing Data](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Reusing%20and%20Sharing%20Data.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using aliases, but we may look at cloning in the future.

Comment: Great! Aliases don't support the exact path structure you have above so I didn't mention them, but they're definitely covered in the document I mentioned. Glad you found a solution. If my answer helped get you there, feel free to mark it as the answer.